# Java Swing vs C#.net desktop database application

Tags: c#, java, swing, desktop-application

So I'm planning on making a little desktop application that fetches TV-series information from an API and puts them in a database. I will then use this info to keep track of which episodes I watched etc etc (A bit like a desktop version of http://www.myepisodes.com)
Now I've done some research around stackoverflow but I'm still not sure which language will be the best.

Java swing using JavaDB or C#.net using MSSQL? (or even another alternative). What are the advantages / disadvantages of the two?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specifics of JavaDB, but you'd be well advised to use an ORM framework.  In any case, there's no effecitve difference between the languages/packages available for a project of this nature.

Comment: Suggest close: not a good SO question as it has no single best possible answer.

Answer (score 3):

All else being equal, choose the language that maximizes your programming joy.

If you're targeting Windows, use C#.  If you're targeting a cross platform product, Java's not the worst choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want easier cross platform compatibility go with Java, otherwise it seems like a personal preference. LINQ is very useful for queries in C# so you might want to check that out too.

If you find you really want to use C# but also want cross platform look at developing it using Mono: http://mono-project.com

Answer (score 0):

I personally find Swing to be a total pain to work with, but XAML/C# is quite nice. C#'s native events make it much easier to program an event-based UI.

LINQ is also amazing for any sort of data queries you might need.